# Using dolphin with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, dolphin

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 but would like to use dolphin as file manager which I am accustomed to. There are some issues with dolphin usage though.

1. First of all it does not preview images. I followed the instructions
   from [here](https://harishnavnit.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/enabling-file-previews-in-dolphin/) but does not seem to have changed something after. In
   my dolphin nothing is shown in the list in 
   `Settings->Configure Dolphin...->General->Previews`. 
   That seems peculiar enough. Should I log out or something for system to be informed?
2. Also, `image size` as option although present in the menu it's not actual visible by me. There appear a list (which is updated since I can arrange my images by this attribute) but nothing appear in dolphin.
3. Finally, if a file is selected and I hover over it with mouse pointer it's disappearing (it becomes white and I cannot distinguish it from the background).

Any idea if it has to do with the combination Ubuntu (unity) + dolphin or something? If I should not expect much from this combination or if I can solve these issues?